# Generate HTML from Eclipse update site

Tags: eclipse, eclipse-plugin, p2, update-site

I'd like to generate a HTML file that takes its content from an Eclipse update site. Ideally it should output organize the content based on categories and include the descriptions somehow.

1. Input: Eclipse Update Site
2. ???
3. Profit!! (HTML page)

I'm sure there is a tool like this, or perhaps I can do this right now from Eclipse?

Comment: I like this idea.  It would save a lot of confusion for new users to Eclipse who often complain that update sites are broken (when they really just don't have an index.html).  Unfortunately, I don't have any suggestions except using some xml transformer on the content.xml or the category.xml.

Answer (score 0):

Have a look at this update site http://download.eclipse.org/graphiti/updates/0.8.1/

What they seem to have done? Well inside their P2Repo content they have added just an index.html

What can you do? Write an index.html for your content or you can write an xslt transformation and pick up and render the content from site.xml itself

Comment: What I was looking for was a tool that creates the index.html file for me with some nice output, not just dumping/transforming the xml file.